# Adding more product from contact form 7 to woocommerce checkout

Tags: wordpress, contacts, contact-form-7, hook-woocommerce

I am creating an order form that sells sim and i have a dropdown menu that list option to top up i want once a customer select an option it add to cart and then link a button to the checkout page

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is very vague and will maybe not receive an answer. Please read again and follow our posting guide [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! You can [edit] your question to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on_sent_ok is deprecated in latest version of contact form 7, but alternate way is:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
location = 'http://www.yoursite.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=ID';}, false );
```

Comment: Where should it be placed?

Comment: You can use in in .js file or footer.php file but the proper way is use this code in functions.php file like this:

add_action('wp_footer', 'YOUR_FUNCTION');

function YOUR_FUNCTION(){
 echo "<script>...</script>";
}